# windows 7 install on a 1tb sata 3 hd comes up with error on completing install. error says windows could not configure hardware

Tags: windows-7, installation

My specs are:

- Gigabyte 78lmt-usb3 Motherboard
- AMD FX 6300 six core processor
- Alpine 750W power supply
- 8GB DDR3 Corsair Vengeance ram
- 1TB TOSHIBA SATA 3 6GB 7200rpm hard drive

My problem after the whole install on the completing install. I have an error that says Windows could not configure hardware.

I am very confused as to why this doesn't work. Windows 7 x64 bit install worked fine on old hard drive which was also SATA.

Comment: Does it tell you what hardware?

Comment: no just says hardware

Answer (score -2):

Someone else want to find his boot time driver ?

It's an Advanced format drive and you use the F5 / install additional hardware driver during the installation.

This is requirement server drivers installing on fresh RAID arrays are accustomed to.

Based on the problem, it is surmised you initiated the installation while booted into your existing working old SATA drive version of Windows or are you doing this with an install CD directly to your new naked 1TB drive.

Congratulations, nice computer.

Comment: straight to new 1tb. but just reinstalled on old hard drive to do as you said. seen another post close to mine qhich mentioned same. many thanks was a great deal so saving pennies for graphics now